# Minification error with django compressor

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

I'm using an automatic minification tool called django compressor. However django compressor minification seems to introduce errors.

**Updated script with semicolons:**

**Before:**

```
   var app = angular.module('loginApp', [
    "ngRoute",
    "ngAnimate",
    "ngTouch",
    "mobile-angular-ui",
    "ui.router",
    "app.factories.storage",
    "app.controllers.login",
    "angular-loading-bar"


]);


app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "/static/html/profile/login.html",
            controller: "loginController"
        })

        .state('register', {
            url: "/register",
            templateUrl: "/static/html/profile/register.html",
            controller: "loginController"
        });

});
```

After:

```
var app=angular.module("loginApp",["ngRoute","ngAnimate","ngTouch","mobile-angular-ui","ui.router","app.factories.storage","app.controllers.login","angular-loading-bar"]);app.config(function(e,t){t.otherwise("/");e.state("login",{url:"/",templateUrl:"/static/html/profile/login.html",controller:"loginController"}).state("register",{url:"/register",templateUrl:"/static/html/profile/register.html",controller:"loginController"})})
```

**Error:**

```
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error 
Module 'loginApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Error URL:

[https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr...](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=loginApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.19%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DloginApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.19%2Fangular.min.js:6:450%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.19%2Fangular.min.js:20:466%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.19%2Fangular.min.js:21:469%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.19%2Fangular.min.js:33:267%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.19%2Fangular.min.js:7:280)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.19%2Fangular.min.js:33:207)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20dc%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.19%2Fangular.min.js:36:309)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.19%2Fangular.min.js:18:139)

**Update:** It appears django compressor is not the issue, even using an online tool still gave the same error.... **http://jscompress.com/ **

The results were unminify = no errors, minify = errors

This is what seems to generate the error:

```
app.config(function(e,t){t.otherwise("/");e.state("login",{url:"/",templateUrl:"/static/html/profile/login.html",controller:"loginController"}).state("register",{url:"/register",templateUrl:"/static/html/profile/register.html",controller:"loginController"})})
```

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: @yuvi I'm using 1.2.19

Comment: It's weird actually. The description of the error seems to fit a the template for the [nomod error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod) rather than `$injector:modulerr`... Do you have `ngRoute` installed?

Comment: Also - are you getting the error from the original uncached and unminimized files? Seems to me this isn't related to django-compressor

Comment: @yuvi yes I have ngRoute root install. This file works perfectly when not minified. I get no errors at all. I just minified one file called login.js which has the above and this is what happends.

Comment: I have added the error URL in OP

Comment: @yuvi I have updated the OP. Even when I take the code and use an online tool (straight cut and paste) I get the sane error. The unmodified version works perfectly tho.

Comment: Ok this is silly, but try re-calling the module, i.e. add `var app = angular.module('loginApp');` right after defining it (but before configuring it). What happens?

Comment: @yuvi recalling did not work :(. However, app.config is where this errors. If I minify just the top part code it works. As soon as I minify the app.conf() I get the 'loginApp' error.

Comment: Right, you have an error there - you're missing a semi-colon after `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")`

Comment: @yuvi still no joy this gives the same error when adding semi-colon. Will update OP with new script

Comment: You have another one. See my answer below.

Comment: Wait - the original code you provided uses `app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) { ... });` while the one you mentioned below uses `app.config(function(e,t){ ... });`. I know that might seem the same, but it isn't. Angular is special like that about namespaces and regular minifying that will work for most javascript code won't work for it. So which one is it?

Comment: dam it @yuvi yep you are right. the version That worked is the first (once I added your semicolons)!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two semicolons missing:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/") // <--- HERE

    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "/static/html/profile/login.html",
            controller: "loginController"
        })

        .state('register', {
            url: "/register",
            templateUrl: "/static/html/profile/register.html",
            controller: "loginController"
        }) // <--- HERE

});
```

It's generally a good rule of thumb to always run javascript code through [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) before minimizing (especially angular code which tends to really hate being minified...)

Comment: @Sputnik As for my comment on minifying angular code without messing up the namespaces, you should [read this](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) (scroll down to "a note on minification"). Generally, you need to always inject the variables through an array, so when you convert `$foo` to `a` it will keep the original identity. [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) makes this easier to do